# SICStus Prolog sat_count/2 replacement?

Tags: prolog, sat, clpb

SWI-Prolog CLP(B) has a sat_count/2 predicate. What
would be the replacement for this in SICStus Prolog CLP(B)?
So far I went with:

```
sat_count(+[1|L], N) :-
   aggregate_all(count, L^labeling(L), N).
```

But the above is just using labeling brute force, so not
really an intelligent solution. Is there a better way to do
sat_count/2 in SICStus Prolog?